# Why no 'the' in "embrace grammatical reform"

Tags: definite-article

> This proves difficult with anaphoric reference to quantified variables, where English grammar calls for constructions such as 'If someone is from Chicago he likes big cities.' and ' Anyone who loves Eve loves himself.' My solution is **to embrace grammatical reform** and use a plural pronoun: 'If someone is from  Chicago they like big cities.' and 'Anyone who loves Eve loves themself.'

Why is it not **to embrace *the* grammatical reform**. It is a particular reform concerning a particular language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My solution is to embrace grammatical reform and use a plural pronoun.*

First to clarify, this excerpt suggests one can solve the gender-neutral pronoun problem by using plural pronouns like *they*. **To see why "the grammatical reform" is not used, let's just simplify and transform the sentence:**

- Embrace grammatical reform. (This is the core imperative sentence.)
- Embrace reform.
- Embrace change. (Hypernym)
- Change! (Semantically (nearly) equal.)

The author is suggesting that one can "embrace reform" by the method suggested -- rather than "embrace the reform" as if it's some aforementioned or understood grammar-reform-movement.  We parse the sentence like this:

- Embrace change and use a plural pronoun. (Correct)
- Embrace the change and use a plural pronoun.* (Incorrect. What change?)

**It's all a matter of perspective.**  The OP's thinking that *"the reform" actually does exist so why didn't the author refer to it as such?* The author may or may not think of it that way. But the author is gently persuading people. It would be too strong to say "embrace the grammatical reform" -- as if the author is joining some reform movement. (Who's leading this reform movement? Is it a bunch of radicals? What would my neighbors/peers think if they knew I embraced this reform movement?)

Comment: This is a good answer.  I'd say it improves on mine.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You make some good points, but nevertheless we're still not actually talking about a specific reform.  The fact that it's a grammatical reform doesn't make it specific, nor does the fact that it's a reform of a particular language.  As a more obvious analogue, "eating baked salmon" doesn't use "the" because it doesn't refer to a specific fish, even though it refers to a particular way of preparing a particular type of fish.

It's even more confusing because it would be correct to say "embrace the reform of (English) grammar."  But then we are embracing a specific reform, the reform of English grammar.  (Note that we don't say "the reform of the English grammar," because again it is grammar in general.)  So, what we are embracing is grammatical reform in general, from which the suggested behavior (using the plural pronoun) proceeds.

Comment: I like the explanation. But can't we read it as a specific reform--the reform that suggests using *they* as a neuter singular pronoun--too?

Comment: @Fantasier Interesting.  That indeed sounds like an alternative, but in that case I would think it would be "a grammatical reform" (the using of the plural pronoun) since we haven't yet said which grammatical reform we're talking about.